# Rails error: Index name '...' on table '...' already exists while running rails db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations

So I'm working with a colleague who added some additional migration files and per normal procedure once I pulled their version I ran rails db:migrate. I end up getting the following errors:

```
 Index name 'index_authorizations_on_user_id' on table 'authorizations' already exists

 ArgumentError: Index name 'index_authorizations_on_user_id' on table 'authorizations' already exists
```

So I went and checked the schema and the table is already present. So why is it failing? Typically in the past it only generates new table entries/updates when doing a migration so why isn't it just ignoring it?

I've tried doing a rollback and get:
This migration uses remove_columns, which is not automatically reversible.

I've tried doing bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development and I get the same errors.

I've done a db:reset, db:drop, and it all comes back to an issue with pending migrations that I cannot get to run. What am I doing wrong?

They added the following migration: 20171024074328_create_authorizations.rb

```
 class CreateAuthorizations < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :authorizations do |t|
      t.string :provider
      t.string :uid
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps

      add_index :authorizations, :user_id
      add_index :authorizations, [:provider, :uid], unique: true
    end
  end
```

end

Comment: Would you show the migration?

Comment: Added the migration file in question

Comment: Dropping the database should delete all pending migrations.  Is there an earlier migration that creates the table and index?

Comment: @TomAranda Dropping the database is an absolute last resort and often causes more problems (such as data loss or doing nothing at all if you backup-drop-restore to avoid losing all your data) that it solves.

Comment: @muistooshort, A fair point.  I did not mean to recommend that course of action, and I do not recommend that course of action.  However, the user said he already tried that, so I was puzzled why it didn't work.

Answer (score 8):

This:

```
t.references :user, foreign_key: true
```

adds an index on `authorizations.user_id` for you. If you check the [`references` documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Table.html#method-i-references) it will point you at [`add_reference`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_reference) and that says:

> `:index`
>   Add an appropriate index. Defaults to true. [...]

So `index: true` is the default when you call `t.references :user` and that creates the same index that `add_index :authorizations, :user_id` creates.

Comment: Tried to resolve this by removing add_index :authorizations, :user_id
      add_index :authorizations, [:provider, :uid], unique: true

Comment: So you removed `add_index :authorizations, :user_id` and re-ran your migrations?

Comment: It actually errors with this instead: PG::DuplicateTable: ERROR:  relation "authorizations" already exists
: CREATE TABLE "authorizations" ("id" bigserial primary key, "provider" character varying, "uid" character varying, "user_id" bigint, "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_4ecef5b8c5"

Comment: Did you create the table by hand somewhere? Something else out of the ordinary? Each migration should run inside a transaction and PostgreSQL supports DDL transactions (i.e. it can rollback schema changes) so the whole migration should run or not run. That `PG::DuplicateTable` exception is telling you that something created the `authorizations` table before you tried to run the updated migration.

Answer (score 0):

So the only thing that I've found that "worked" was to actually delete the migration files then run rails db:migrate. Didn't catch on anything, no errors.

Not a fan of the fact that this worked.

Comment: If this is the only thing that worked for you, then there is an issue with your migrations.  In the above comment you stated that you received a different error - had you rolled back the migration, removed the relevant lines, and then rerun it?  The correct solution here is to fix the migrations - deleting the files will do nothing for someone who subsequently comes along and checks them out of version control.

Comment: So I was able to get it to work after messing up in deployment to Heroku. I recreated the merge files without add_index and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Check if it's a table or a changed table, most times you need to drop the table or delete the column then run the migration again and it'll be good to go

Answer (score 0):

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945795/is-it-possible-to-change-column-index-in-rails-3-migration) for me was to drop the indexed column that had a `unique` constraint and then reindex

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).